# Subgroups of Symmetric Group $S_4$ and Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

During my Algebra class we were given this exercise to solve at home, but I couldn't find any solution and I also did not really get the one our teacher gave us. So, the text was:

> Given G = S<sub>4</sub> = Sym({1, 2, 3, 4}). Then:
>
> 1. Is there a subgroup of G of order 5? Motivate your answer.
> 2. Give and example of two subgroups H<sub>1</sub> and H<sub>2</sub> so that |H<sub>1</sub>| = |H<sub>2</sub>| and H<sub>1</sub> $\ncong$ H<sub>2</sub> (H<sub>1</sub> not isomorphic to H<sub>2</sub>)

Part 1 of the question is fairly simple in fact thanks to Lagrange Theorem on subgroups, but the problems arise with Part 2. The given solution is:

> Let's consider as an example:
>
> 1. H<sub>1</sub> = { id, (1,2), (3,4), (1,2)(3,4) }
> 2. H<sub>2</sub> = { id, (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3) }
>
> In fact, H<sub>1</sub> elements are all of order 2 (apart from id = identity ) while (1,2,3,4) $\in$ H<sub>2</sub> has order 4. Thus H<sub>1</sub> $\ncong$ H<sub>2</sub> ( H<sub>1</sub> not isomorphic with H<sub>2</sub> )

I've tried my best, but given the fact that our teacher sometimes is very messy I still can not figure out why this is a valid proof, nor the steps needed to find it. This is my first time posting, so sorry in advance for any mistake. Thank you for your time!

Comment: $S_4$ has order not divisible by $5$, hence no subgroup or order $5$ is in there. $C_4$ and $C_2\times C_2$ are groups of order $4$ that are nonisomorphic, hence by Cayley we may embedd then in $S_4$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

(1,2)(3,4) is a different permutation from (1,2,3,4), and the correct group for $H_2$ is {id,(1,2,3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4,3,2)}.